# Alert Handling in Robot Framework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I have to handle 2 alert message of one pop-up but it's validating only one alert. kindly refer below screenshot.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8GPL.png)

**Code option1:**

```
Handle Alert    * Country Description is required.* Currency is required.  Leave  
sleep  2
Handle Alert    ACCEPT
```

**Code:option2:**

```
Alert Should Be Present        * Country Description is required. LEAVE
Alert Should Be Present        * Currency is required.        LEAVE
Handle Alert    ACCEPT
```

I Tried both options but it's not working

Comment: Hi Reyansh. 1. The screenshot shows that there is only one alert! I.e. Alert is the whole window. So if you have a popup modal window with two or more lines of text, then it is still ONE alert.   2. Pay attention, that keyword `Alert Should Be Present` closes the window by default!. So, it verifies text and immediately Accepts it.

Comment: Could not check it, but theoretically your way should be to check both messages of the window in one command, e.g.:
`Alert Should Be Present        * Country Description is required.\n* Currency is required.`
where `\n` is newline character to represent multiline text.
[documentation](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Alert%20Should%20Be%20Present)

Comment: Hi Sam  I Tried with \n but it's not taking. Have you any idea or have you seen anywhere 2 alert messages in one popup modal window?

Answer (score 0):

**1**. You could use it in one line as

`Alert Should Be Present   <Whole text of your alert here>`

**2**. Or if you are not sure how to extract expected text from Alert for the first time, you could get it from your test report after execution and copy as expected message/ E.g. copy from ${actual_message} variable:

```
${actual_message} =  Handle Alert   LEAVE   # Leave alert open and get its message.
Should be equal  ${actual_message}   * Country Descript...blah-blah
```

[Handle Alert doc](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Handle%20Alert)

Comment: code: Set Focus To Element    id:add
           Click Element           id:add 
           Element Text Should Be    xpath://*[@id='countryMasterForm']/fieldset[1]/legend    Country Master
        Element Should Be Focused    id:countryDes
             Sleep  2
             Set Focus To Element    id:save
                  Click Element    id:save
                 Handle Alert          * Country Description is required.\n * Currency is required.
                     sleep  4
                  Handle Alert    ACCEPT

Comment: Result: LoginPage :: Login Test For Capital India                             [ WARN ] Ignoring space after '\n' is deprecated. For more info see: https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/3333
[ WARN ] Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on failure: UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: * Country Description is required.
* Currency is required.
Message: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : * Country Description is required.
* Currency is required.

Comment: try to remove `\n` then or replace it with a space character. My main guess is that your expected alert text is not equal exactly to the actual alert message. Could be there extra space(s) character somewhere? My advice is to expect the actual alert text carefully and copy it as expected text into the test.